# What is the meaning of ~ apart from logical not?

Tags: matlab

What does following code do in Matlab? I searched documentation but `~` shows *logical not*. But I could not relate following output to anything about *logical not*.

```
[~, k ] = max([0.9 1.5 4.6; 3.31 0.76 5.4]
Output: 2 1 2
```

Comment: `~` just ignores that particular output from the function. `[M,k]=max(x)` returns `M`, the maximum value(s), and `k`, the location(s) of the maximum values(s). If you aren't interested in the value(s), you don't need to make a variable `M`, you can ignore the output using`~`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~` placeholder allows you to ignore an output from a function. Using this allows you to acknowledge that something is output by the function, but you do not have to allocate a variable to store the output in.

When a function returns values in Matlab the number of parameters it returns and the order of these parameters is important and allows you to know what each returned value is. You may sometimes come across situations where a function returns more values than you are interested in, and you can ignore the ones you are not interested in using `~`.

In your example, `M = max([0.9 1.5 4.6])` would return only the maximum value. If you want to know the index of the maximum value, you have to use `[M,I] = max([[0.9 1.5 4.6])`. If you need to know the index of the maximum value but are not interested in the actual value itself, you can use `[~,I] = max([0.9 1.5 4.6])`, and you thus do not need to allocate a variable to hold the maximum values.

Answer (score 3):

The according reference you're looking for is the [**Symbol Reference**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html), which states:

> Tilde — ~
>
> The tilde character is used in comparing arrays for unequal values,
>   finding the logical NOT of an array, and as a placeholder for an input
>   or output argument you want to omit from a function call. Not Equal to
>
> ...
>
> Argument Placeholder
>
> To have the fileparts function return its third output value and skip
>   the first two, replace arguments one and two with a tilde character:
>
> `[~, ~, filenameExt] = fileparts(fileSpec);`

which is what @David suggested in his comment.